# Calling superclass method in superclass in Python

Tags: python, oop, prototypal-inheritance, python-class

I call superclass method from subclass (`bazz1 = super().foo(raw=raw, arg2=arg2, **kwargs)`). In the superclass method I have another call to other superclass method (`return bazz1 if raw else self.process(bazz1)`).

What happens during the execution time is something I did not expected. I defined that `SuperClass` calls `self.process(bazz1)` from `def foo(...)`. What happens instead of entering `SuperClass.process(...)`, the execution enters `DerivedClass.process(...)`. Is there a way to explicitly prevent this?

```
class UltraClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        super().__init__()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def bar(self, arg1, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        pass


class SuperClass(UltraClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        super().__init__(arg1)

    def foo(self, raw, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        ...
        bazz1 = get_bazz(...)
        return bazz1 if raw else self.process(bazz1)

    def process(self, bazz1, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        return bazz1

class DerivedClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        super().__init__(arg1)

    def foo(self, raw, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        ...
        bazz1 = super().foo(raw=raw, arg2=arg2, **kwargs)
        return bazz1 if raw else self.process(bazz1)

    def process(self, bazz1, **kwargs) -> bazz:
        ...
        ...
        ...
        return bazz1
```

Comment: Your statement `What happens in the execution time is that subclass method is called. What would be the correct way to call superclass method?` is unclear. Can you please elaborate on what you mean. Call the superclass emthod from where? How are you calling the function in runtime?

Comment: Also, in your code `SuperClass` does not inherit from another class.

Comment: Where does `bazz1` come from for `SuperClass.foo` to return?

Comment: If your superclass needs to call its own version of a method  that has been overridden, then your class structure is flawed.  You need to rethink your design.  The whole point of subclassing is to allow the subclass to be in control.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a base class to *only* ever be calling its own version of a certain method, you can explicitly call the method on the class, passing `self` around manually:

```
class Base:
    def foo(self):
        pass

    def no_derivs(self):
        Base.foo(self)  # only ever call our own foo method, not any overriden version
```

But that's seldom a good idea. Usually if a subclass overrides a method, it does so because that method needs to behave differently or the subclass's logic will be broken. If the base class's version of the method would have worked, it wouldn't have been overridden in the first place.

So, as Tim Roberts commented, if you think you need this behavior, it suggests that your class hierarchy design is flawed. Either the derived class shouldn't be overriding some of the base class methods, or the base class should be content calling the derived versions of those methods (which can call the base version of the methods, if necessary, via `super`).